# If true....delete specific cells, not the entire row in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a column (B) with checkboxes. What I would like is if a checkbox in a specific row is checked (true), I want to be able to run a script which will delete only specific cells in that row but not the entire row. Is it possible?

exemple: if B9 is true then delete cells C9 to T9
(The entire sheet goes up to V9 but I want to protect this area)

The scripts I have  done so far delete the entire row

The best would be to delete specific cells and move the data in other cells up , ideally. I have a pre-made button on my sheet to run the script so I don’t need the process to be automatic when something in column "B" is checked (true). I want the function to be activated only when the button on the sheet itself is pressed and I'm okay with that part.

Here is a picture of my template joined

Here is the code I have written:

```
function deleterowsifchecked() {
 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const ws = ss.getSheetByName ("The Ultimate To Do List")

  const co1Adata = ws.getRange("B:B").getValues()

  for(let i =co1Adata.length-1;i>= 0;i--){
    if(co1Adata[i][0] === true){
      ws.deleteRow(i+1)
  }
} 

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMn9E.png)

Comment: Here you do not specify what you wish to delete - is it the `colAdata` range?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you check the checkboxes in column "B" and run the script by clicking a button, you want to delete columns "C" to "T" of the checked rows using Google Apps Script.
- When the cells are deleted, you want to move other cells to up.
- In your situation, you want to run the script by clicking a button on Spreadsheet. You are not required to run the script by the trigger.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and confirm the sheet name again. And save the script.

```js
function deleterowsifchecked() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("The Ultimate To Do List");
  const range = ws.getRange("B1:B" + ws.getLastRow());
  const ranges = range.getValues().reduce((ar, [b], i) => {
    if (b === true) {
      ar.push(`C${i + 1}:T${i + 1}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length == 0) return;
  ws.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges().reverse().forEach(r => r.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS));
  range.uncheck(); // If you want to uncheck the checkboxes after the script is finished, please use this line.
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [deleteCells(shiftDimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension)

Comment: Thanks everyones for your help. @Tanaike Thank you so much...this was EXACTLY what I was trying to do. I am so happy and so grateful. Wow it works! Thank you...I know I am not supposed to use the comments sections but where can I say thanks otherwise...if one day you need help for growing amazing house plants remember me..Have an amazing day! :))

Comment: @Lucie Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I’m happy enough with just your feeling of thanks. Thank you, too, and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out what you need to delete but we can simply set a range and then delete that.  Here I used `C1:F1` for an example.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension

```js
function deleterowsifchecked() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = sheet.getSheetByName("The Ultimate To Do List");
  const co1Adata = ws.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var range = ws.getRange("C1:F1");
  range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);
}
```